# Video as background

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

I am trying to add video as background, but it does not work.

This is the code i am using:

```
import UIKit
import MediaPlayer
import AVFoundation
import AVKit
import MediaPlayer

class WelcomeViewController: UIViewController {

    let moviePlayerController = AVPlayerViewController()
    var aPlayer = AVPlayer()
    func playBackgroundMovie(){
        if let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("WelcomeVideo", withExtension: "mp4") {
            aPlayer = AVPlayer(URL: url)
        }
        moviePlayerController.player = aPlayer
        moviePlayerController.view.frame = view.frame
        moviePlayerController.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
        moviePlayerController.view.sizeToFit()
        moviePlayerController.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect
        moviePlayerController.showsPlaybackControls = false
        moviePlayerController.view.userInteractionEnabled = false
        aPlayer.play()
        view.insertSubview(moviePlayerController.view, atIndex: 0)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        self.moviePlayerController.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()

        playBackgroundMovie()
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "didPlayToEndTime", name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification, object: nil)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func didPlayToEndTime(){
        aPlayer.seekToTime(CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0, 1))
        aPlayer.play()
    }
}
```

When I run my application, it crashes as line:

```
aPlayer = AVPlayer(URL: url!)
```

I have added the "WelcomeVideo.mp4" in my project also:

[image]

As you can see on the image, the "WelcomeVideo.mp4" is right next the the current view controller class... What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

Fixed myself! Forgot i had to add it to the **Copy Bundle Resorces** in **Build Phases**.

Comment: I was just writing that in my answer :) Anyways, another thing you should keep in mind is that you shouldn't use forced unwrapping when you are not completely sure that returned that value is not nil (URLForResource function returns NSURL? which is optional and might be nil). You should use optional binding instead to access the optional in a safe way.

Comment: @Whirlwind - Do you mean like i did now? (Check question for updated code)

Comment: @Whirlwind I quick question. The WelcomeVideo.mp4 is just a view, not with sound, but when i am plying music from music app or Spotify, my current music stops when this player is showing. How can i prevent that?

Comment: Yup that is how you should check & unwrap the optional's value. Still, I would wrap everything in that if let, because if there is no video file, there is no reason to initialize and setup a player at all. And, about sound...You will be probably fine by setting up AVAudioSession and set category to AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient. But you should really  ask another question, because this is the whole another topic.

Answer (score 1):

```
if let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "small", ofType: ".mp4") {
    let filePathURL = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: filePath)
    let player = AVPlayer(url: filePathURL)
    let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
    playerController.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    playerController.player = player
    self.present(playerController, animated: true) {
        player.play()
    }
}
```